# Passing data to another view controller, using custom struct datatype, initialiser needed?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

How do I pass data to another view controller when a custom structure datatype is used? The problem I think I'm having is defining the variables in the second view controller.

This is how I'm passing data to the next view controller:

```
let sessionDetailsViewController = segue.destination as! SessionDetailsViewController

let indexPathRow = sender as! Int
sessionDetailsViewController.session = myFeed[indexPathRow]
```

Where `session` is of the structure datatype, `Feed`.

Then in my `SessionDetailsViewController` I'm trying to set the `session` variable like so:

```
var session: Feed
```

However if I do this, I get an error about no initialisers. So I tried implementing an initialiser like so:

```
init(session: Feed) {
    self.session = session

    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented, SessionDetailedViewController")
}
```

The app compiles, then when I trigger the segue to this class, it crashes on the fatalError call.

Previously before I was using the `Feed` structure datatype, I had been using `NSDictionary`, which I defined like so:

```
var session = NSDictionary()
```

This worked fine. If I try and take the same approach for `Feed`, Xcode tries to make me create a new `Feed` object will all its parameters (as expected, as I'm aware `()` creates a new instance).

So how do I pass the required parameters to this view controller? Also, is there a way to make sure this controller is always instantiated with these parameters (as I assume this would be good coding practice)?

Comment: "However if I do this, I get an error about no initialisers." Yep, you should just define it as `var session: Feed!` and be done with it. It's one of the few appropriate uses of implicitly unwrapped optionals.

Comment: @Rob, awesome, that worked. Am I doing this the right way, or should I be using an initialiser?

Comment: If you're manually instantiating your view controller you can create your own initializer and not make it optional. But if you're planning on possibly using this view controller in a segue (where it always calls `init(coder:)` and then `prepare(for:sender:)`, then make it an optional.

Comment: Ah ok. Is it fine to leave this as non-optional like `var session: Feed!`? Since the view controller will always need this parameter. I am segueing to this view controller. Also, feel free to copy your comments into an answer, and I'll accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare `session` to be an implicitly unwrapped optional (which will be set in `prepare(for:sender:)` of the view controller from which the segue was initiated). No custom `init` is needed.

```
var session: Feed!
```

To be clear, `Feed!` is an optional. It's just an "implicitly unwrapped" optional (where it's implicitly unwrapped wherever you use it). It's used in cases where the logic in your app dictates that it might not be set by the time `init` is complete, but once it's time to actually use it, it will always be set, which is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare session as an optional.  Anything you don't give a value to at initialization time needs to be optional.

```
var session: Feed?
```

Also are you in the prepareForSegue call? I would code it like this.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }
    let sessionAtIndexPath = myFeed[indexPath.row]
    (segue.destination as! SessionDetailsViewController).session = sessionAtIndexPath
}
```